# Why admob cause high cpu after android app paused or stopped

Tags: android, admob, cpu

I have two application, both using Admob, one with mediation and another one just admob. Those app written since android 2.3, no problem until Android 4 released. Now my users complaining about high cpu usage, after application closed or paused (even without starting service)

I have struggle to find the cause but no solution yet, what i found is when ads from Admob shown, high cpu usage started after pressing home. But when ads not yet shown, no problem

Im using android 4.3 and cpu usage monitored using battery setting and cpu usage from Developer option.

Would like to revise question if more info needed. Please help

Comment: I am facing the same issue, the activity is not at the front but CPU is 10 to 11% . same app with no admob banner CPU 0 % did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Activity handles moving to background appropriately:

```
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  adView.stopLoading(); // Remember to startLoading again in #onResume
}

public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  adView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but the app still running after pressing Back or Home. When in background, cpu usage is higher

Comment: Your app will still be running, that is standard as part of the Android lifecycle. The question is what is causing the high CPU. If you have stopped Admob then it is not it. what do your logs say?

Comment: Yes, I mean "running", in EMPTY state or BACKGROUND state. But in Android 4 behave differently, using *top* or *cpu usage from Developer option*, my app stay on top using cpu

Comment: So what does the log says? Post that. If it is Admob you will see it.